# Can I use PBOs for textures in iOS?

Tags: opengl-es, ios, opengl-es2

As far as I can see, there is no `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`. Also, the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification (and as far as I know, no iOS device currently supports OpenGL ES > 2.0) states that `glMapBufferOES()` can only use `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` as a target, yet `glTexImage2D()` and `glTexSubImage2D()` only seem to use PBOs if `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` is bound.

The [OpenGL documentation for `glBindBuffer()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindBuffer.xml) also states that:

> `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER` and `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` are available only if the GL version is **2.1 or greater**.

So, can I use PBOs for textures? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL ES doesn't have pixel buffer objects. So you can not use them there.

Answer (score 7):

[OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/registry/) and [OpenGL ES](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/), despite the similar names, are two *different* specifications. They may have similarly named functions, but there will be semantic differences between what these functions do. And of course, there will be differences in what features they support.

PBOs are not supported on ES (except for ES 3.0, which recently came out but isn't widely supported yet), regardless of version. There isn't even an extension for it. Also, you should probably read up on [what PBOs actually do](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object); they don't do what you think they do.